# nginx subsfilter regex to delete one html tag

Tags: regex, filter, nginx

I use the nginx subs filter module to remove an html tag from a page.

the tag is :

```
<div id="header">
```

It is immediatly followed by :

```
 <div id="mainscreen">
```

I tried :

```
subs_filter <div\ id=\"header\">.*<div\ id\"mainscreen\"> <div\ id=\"mainscreen\"> r;
subs_filter <div\ id=\"header\">(.*)<div\ id\"mainscreen\"> <div\ id=\"mainscreen\"> r;
subs_filter <div\ id=\"header\">(.*?)<div\ id\"mainscreen\"> <div\ id=\"mainscreen\"> r;
subs_filter <div\ id=\"header\">(.*?\n)*<div\ id\"mainscreen\"> <div\ id=\"mainscreen\"> r;
```

But nothing changes.

Here is what I want to remove:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="topline">
<div class="topleft">

    <a class="about-link" onclick="UI.show_about(this);return false" id="rcmbtn100" href="#">A propos</a>
        </div>

<div class="topright">

        <span class="username">michee.test@test.com</span>
    <a class="button-logout" id="rcmbtn101" href="./?_task=logout" onclick="return rcmail.command('switch-task','logout',this,event)">Déconnexion</a>

</div>
</div>

<div id="topnav">
<div id="taskbar" class="topright">
<a class="button-mail" id="rcmbtn102" href="./?_task=mail" onclick="return rcmail.command('switch-task','mail',this,event)"><span class="button-inner">Courriel</span></a>
<a class="button-addressbook" id="rcmbtn103" href="./?_task=addressbook" onclick="return rcmail.command('switch-task','addressbook',this,event)"><span class="button-inner">Carnet d'adresses</span></a>

<a class="button-settings" id="rcmbtn104" href="./?_task=settings" onclick="return rcmail.command('switch-task','settings',this,event)"><span class="button-inner">Paramètres</span></a>
<a class="button-logout" id="rcmbtn105" href="./?_task=logout" onclick="return rcmail.command('switch-task','logout',this,event)"><span class="button-inner">Déconnexion</span></a>
<span class="minmodetoggle"></span>
</div>
<img src="skins/larry/images/roundcube_logo.png" id="toplogo" border="0" alt="Logo" onclick="rcmail.command('switch-task','mail');return false;">
</div>

<br style="clear:both" />
</div>




<div id="mainscreen">
```

Comment: I think you are missing the equal sign `=` in the first `<div\ id\"mainscreen\">`.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thanks. But which one is the good one ?

Comment: Try going for the third one. I don't know how nginx works exactly, but if that still doesn't work, I would suggest `subs_filter <div\ id=\"header\">[\w\W]*?<div\ id\"mainscreen\"> <div\ id=\"mainscreen\"> r;`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. But now that I have my little mistake repaired I will try a bunch of regex.

Answer (score 0):

`subs_filter <div\ id=\"header\">[\s\S]*<div\ id=\"mainscreen\"> <div\ id=\"mainscreen\"> r;`

You were missing the `=`.  I wouldn't use any of the other 3 regexes since you don't need to capture what's between the tags.

Note this will erase `<div id="header">` and everything up to `<div id="mainscreen">` regardless of how far apart they are on the same html page.  If you want a more precise regex then post an example of your actual html.

Comment: Doesn't this replace back one `<div id="mainscreen">`? And don't you think that using a greedy `.*` will mess things up? Does the `.` by default match newlines in nginx?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Erasing everything from header included to mainscreen excluded. But sorry, your rule doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jerry I do think it's too greedy.  That's why an example would be better.  Newlines is a good point.  I'll adjust it.  What do you mean by your first sentence?

Comment: @Jerry Yes.  And that's exactly what Michée wants.

Comment: I edited my question with the html. It is the roundcube header that I want to remove.

Comment: @basher Oh, a misread here, I somehow read that it would erase everything including `<div id="mainscreen">`. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Michée There is no `<div id="mainscreen">`.  Are you looking to remove everything up to `<img src="skins/larry/images/roundcube_logo.png" ....`?

Comment: @Jerry No worries.  There seems to be a lot of miscommunication going on here.

Comment: Yes, there is an id mainscreen at the very bottom. I would like to remove everything in the html example except that tag. I forgot to indent with 4 spaces, so it didn't show when I edited it. Sorry.